# Migrating from one Linux distribution to another

Tags: ubuntu, migration, operating-system

How should I approach **migrating** a server **from Mint to Ubuntu**? I don't know how go about it since I have a lot on my Mint server.

EDIT: I also would like to keep my mail server running, if possible, during the migration.

Comment: One comment regarding uptime: If it is important to you to keep the downtime low, set up the new server on a different machine or VM. Once you are satisfied with the new setup and have tested things like the mail server configuration, simply change the DNS records (e.g. the MX record for your domain) to the new machine. If you perform an in-place reinstall, there is always a chance that something might go wrong and the downtime ends up being longer than expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **This is a matter of completely rebuilding the server from the ground up.**

Remember that this is **not really one task**, but is instead a sequence of smaller tasks that you should seek help with, but you should be OK using these rough steps as an overview.

...

### **1. Move** any **miscellaneous files** not strictly necessary for the servers operation

### **2. Create a VM** to house a test rebuild of the server

### **3. Start assembling a script**

or set of scripts to automate the build process for the new server when it comes time to build it for real. You can either contain everything in one file, or possibly have each type of step in separate scripts. This is both to prevent any steps from being forgotten, and to save time in the actual build.

An example set of scripts might look like the following
 - Install Dependencies
 - Clone git repo + move config/service/etc. files if necessary
 - Run any/all other scripts required

### **4. Build test server**

inside the VM and **add each step completed** either **to a script** or a **build log** you maintain yourself. Record everything you did, no detail is too small to include (within reason, coffee breaks can be ommitted).

### **5. Test the test server.**

Be as rigorous as you can in ensuring it is working correctly, **any debugging steps need to be recorded.** As a newbie it can be dangerous to attempt to correct the build steps to include what you needed to do in the debugging stage, as you may simply not know all of the ramifications involved. The safest thing, **expert advice notwithstanding** may be to simply replicate the entire process, things you suspect may be redundant or need to be changed later, included.

### **6. REBUILD**

the server for real.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You essentially have to rebuild your server, but you can at least use the old config files as templates for the new setup.

> I also would like my mail server still up and running if possible this way I can still receive mail while in the process.

Not possible if you do an inplace migration to another OS. Just be quick about it and use the fact that the mail system is designed around this kind of failure and servers will try to deliver the mails again when the server is back up, in most cases for at least two days and often much longer.

Comment: Ok. But how would I approach this. what steps would I have to do? Can you please go into a bit more detail. Thanks.

Comment: No, sorry. This is way too broad and dependent on how your system is set up. The gist is this: Make a backup. Install Ubuntu from scratch and then set it up like you want it, using the config files from the backup as template when appropriate.

Comment: You first should rebuild your environment in a VM to test and get in touch with the system and learn. Second thing to remember is to run a backup of your important data. I don't think that someone can help you with single step by step manual for such a complex task.

Comment: +1 for the VM suggestion @Thomas